# Why doesn't ARM 11 or earlier support Adobe Flash player?

Tags: android, flash, arm

Why doesn't ARM 11 or earlier support Adobe Flash player (Android version)? If you can explain it in depth, you will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a great [thread](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/2335-flash-is-it-working/) on the topic.

Quick rundown; the original versions of the Flash Player DID work on ARMv6 chips (ARM 11), but the experience wasn't good, and made Flash (and therefore Adobe) look bad. By compiling it only for ARMv7 chips, they've limited it to newer/higher end devices to give a better experience. In the end, it wasn't a matter of whether or not it was technically feasible, It was about creating the best user experience and prevent tarnishing Adobe's image [further].

Answer (score 1):

the maipad has working flash for armv6, and if you look up their website it's available to download. may require rooting/custom rom to work on some devices.
see
 http://www.maixin-china.com/software-download.asp

the undisputable fact that flash player all the way to v11 runs fine on armv6 (regardless of what effort it took on the part of the maipad developers) seems to show more that adobe isn't interested in supporting older chipsets than that there's any problems with the software running on older devices.